# how to check for a non-existent parameter

Tags: sql-server

There is this 3rd party software that passes queries to SQL Server, however, I'm having issues when a parameter does not exist. It resolves the empty string without any quotes, thus giving me an invalid SELECT statement.
e.g.

```
-- parameter exists
Select ISNULL('param','') as param1 

-- parameter doesn't exist
Select ISNULL(,'') as param1
```

I know beforehand if the expected parameter is supposed to be string or numeric. When the parameter is numeric, I intend to enclose it in quotes and check if it's a zero-length string. But how do you do the same for strings?

Comment: You can check `@Foo is NULL` to check if a parameter is NULL.  If a parameter _doesn't exist_ then you'll get an error.

Comment: Your question is very unclear: you said that the third-party tool generates invalid SQL, so why not solve that issue? If the tool really behaves the way you described, you should just get rid of it and use something else. It also isn't clear what your workaround about checking zero-length strings actually means or where/how you want to implement it. You also haven't mentioned your version of SQL Server, your programming language and other details of your environment.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for helping. The third party software actually resolves the parameters before passing it to SQL server (2008), and it is just its quirk that it passes nothing when a parameter is not used. What worked for me is this:

Select 'param' + '' as param1